# Xcode 6 - can't return UIImage from method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to return UIImage from method, but Xcode 6 gives me an error - Expected a type.

The thing is, I can't even pass UIImage as a parameter, same error occurs again.

Is there something I don't know about new Xcode or this is just a bug? Is this happening only for me?

If project is created with Xcode 6(dep target iOS 8), it's giving out error in Xcode 5 too, however there's no error when older projects are opened with new Xcode.

Comment: Paste some code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Add @import UIKit; to your class header.

Answer (score 2):

Try including UIKit or create a pch file with it.

I was also having this problem, until I figure out that the new project I created with XCode6 didn't came with the prefix header file (.pch), so the same code that worked on older projects didn't work with the new one because of the missing pch.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen in my previous attempts of this as well as just normal day work with Xcode 6 I would like to say that it is a bug in Xcode 6, @armands-l. Report it as a bug if you haven't already.

I'm very positive that when the next beta of Xcode drops a lot of small things like this will be fixed.

Comment: Except the OP states that the same project gives the same error in Xcode 5 as well. That points to a problem in the code, not Xcode 6.

Comment: But this happens only for projects which are created by Xcode 6. Same code in new Xcode 5 project works without any problem.

Ok, I'm reporting this as a bug.